# How to use code first migrations to update a database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I made a c#.NET WebAPI and it worked, but when I changed the model it stopped working and it gives me the following error message.

> The model backing the 'ApiDbContext' context has changed since the
>   database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update
>   the database.

This is my code:

**The Model (unchanged):**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Test.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        //public DateTime startTime { get; set; }
        //public DateTime endTime { get; set; }
        //public int Age { get; set; }
        //public string Adress { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**The Model (changed):**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Test.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime startTime { get; set; }
        //public DateTime endTime { get; set; }
        //public int Age { get; set; }
        //public string Adress { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**The Controller (changed at updateUser):**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using Test.DBA;
using Test.Models;

namespace Test.Controllers
{
    public class UserAPIController : ApiController
    {
        ApiDbContext dbContext = null;
        public UserAPIController()
        {
            dbContext = new ApiDbContext();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult InsertUser(User user)
        {
            dbContext.Users.Add(user);
            dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Ok(user.Name);
        }

        public IEnumerable<User> GetAllUser()
        {
            var list = dbContext.Users.ToList();
            return list;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult DeleteUser(User user)
        {
            dbContext.Users.Remove(user);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            return Ok(user.Name);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult ViewUser(int id)
        {
            var student = dbContext.Users.Find(id);
            return Ok(student);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult UpdateUser(User user)
        {
            User std = dbContext.Users.Find(user.Id);

            std.Name = user.Name;
            std.startTime = user.startTime;
            //std.endTime = user.endTime;
            //std.Age = user.Age;
            //std.Adress = user.Adress;

            dbContext.Entry(std).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

**DBContext:**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using Test.Models;

namespace Test.DBA
{
    public class ApiDbContext :DbContext
    {
        public ApiDbContext() : base("Connection")
        {

        }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Connection string:**

```cs
<connectionStrings>
   <add name ="Connection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=k;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Type `Enable-Migrations` in package-manager-console, after type `add-migration`, set name, then type `update-database`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/data/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 3):

1. **Enable-Migrations**: Enables the migration in your project by creating a Configuration class.
2. **Add-Migration**: Creates a new migration class as per specified name with the Up() and Down() methods.
3. **Update-Database**: Executes the last migration file created by the Add-Migration command and applies changes to the database schema.

more Details:
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-based-migration-in-code-first.aspx